# Does IRIX 6.5 on an Indy support other web browsers other than Netscape? If so, where can I find them?

Tags: netscape

I have an Indy running on IRIX 6.5. The main web browser cannot run very many websites. Are there any other more modern browsers that I can use to run websites such as wayback machine? When I try to run way back machine, I either get a HTML error message or the browser crashes. I have the internet working, and google works about 50%. Is there a better alternative for IRIX than this 1994 web browser?

Comment: There was a port of Firefox 3 for Irix 6.5.  That puts you forward about 15 years.  I don’t know where you’d find a copy, though,

Comment: http://toastytech.com/guis/irix.html might just possibly be one viable starting point.

Comment: Give https://github.com/tenox7/wrp (Web Rendering Proxy) a try as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure NCSA Mosaic will run on it, but that's a step back, not a step forward.

Comment: X11 allows you to run a browser across the network, like from a modern Linux box (running there, showing here).  Will that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

One step further would be to go to Firefox.

As one comment says there was an attempt to run Firefox 3 on Irix, but those pages are now offline without snapshots at archive.org.

But via  [IRIX Network!](http://www.irix.cc/) at least version 1.5.0.7 is on an [FTP mirror](ftp://ftp.irisware.net/nekoware/) and this is the latest I found: [Firefox 3.0.19](http://mirror.larbob.org/nekoware/current/neko_firefox3.0.19.tardist) ([more](http://mirror.larbob.org/nekoware/diegel/)) – That would bring you from 1994 to [Firefox 3 Release Notes
v3.0.19, released March 30th, 2010](https://website-archive.mozilla.org/www.mozilla.org/firefox_releasenotes/en-US/firefox/3.0.19/releasenotes/)

Or compared to Netscape, maybe [dillo](http://mirror.larbob.org/nekoware/diegel/dillo-3.0.4.1-complete.tardist) 3.0.4.1? With all the awkwardness that comes with dillo as such, that would brig you to [dillo-3.0.4 [April 09, 2014]](https://hg.dillo.org/dillo/raw-file/default/ChangeLog).